# Calling a MVC method is stopping my jQuery from outputting

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller

(A) //The **sigup.inc.php** page

> //Instantiating signup object.;after successfully linking  the signup controller

```
 $newPerson = new Signup_Contr($firstName, $lastName);
```

> //Calling the signupUser() from the controller

```
$result = $newPerson->SignupUser();
```

> //Now if I want to send any json object to ajax; for example:

```
$message = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => "Username already existed"];



echo json_encode($message);
```

//(B): **The problem**
**whenever I include the calling MVC method** in the sigup.inc.php:

```
$result = $newPerson->SignupUser();
```

The jQuery's

> success property

do not output. And when I debug it in Chrome the watch window say:
**response: not available**

However, if **I do not include this method** my jQuery output works perfectly...

HELP will be much appreciated !

Comment: Presumably it's causing an error on the PHP side then. Have you examined the raw response from the server (you can see it in the browser's Network tool if you click on the requst). Have you checked the PHP error log on the server?

Comment: I have checked the php error log and there is no error on the server

Comment: Ok. Silly question but is PHP definitely configured to log errors to a file? And have you also inspected the raw response via the browser's network tool, as I requested?